# How do I enable a DHCP server on a Cisco Aironet 1250 series or 1260 series AP?

Tags: cisco, cisco-commands

I need to enable or disable the DHCP service on one or both of the Cisco APs in the title (well any Cisco AP if there is a standard method), running on running RHEL v15 or v16.

I would very much prefer to be able to do this programmatically, or via commands; but as a last resort if necessary, it may be OK to do it interactively.

Any hints, or pointers or, best of all, detailed instructions gratefully received. TIA

Also, is there a conventional sub-net IP address prefix generally used for air-side subnets, as opposed to wire-side? Or is it the usual 192.168.x.x ?

Comment: I am probably reading this wrong, so confusing myself, but could you clarify the following: How does RHEL fit in here (and I thought the current RHEL was currently v6)?  Are the APs running in autonomous mode or lightweight mode?  Do you want to enable/disable the DHCP service on the AP or enable/disable the AP's interfaces learning an IP through DHCP?  Maybe more details and/or a diagram about what you are trying to accomplish will help as well (what is the end configuration you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: What does _"running on running RHEL v15 or v16"_ mean? Red Hat Enterprise Linux shouldn't have anything to do with Cisco APs.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/access_point/1250/installation/guide/125h_f.html :

```
ip dhcp pool pool_name 
network IP_Network Netmask 
default-router Default_router_IP 
dns-server DNS_Server_IP

Where:

pool_name is the name of the DHCP pool, such as AP1000 or AP1500
IP_Network is the network IP address where the controller resides, such as 10.0.15.1
Netmask is the subnet mask, such as 255.255.255.0
Default_router_IP is the IP address of the default router, such as 10.0.0.1
DNS_Server_IP is the IP address of the DNS server, such as 10.0.10.2
```

Also not sure how RHEL fits into your picture...